# Actualización crtl+f5 windows.reload JavaScript & PHP

Tags: php, javascript

buenos dias , estoy tratando de hacer una actualizacion => ctrol+f5
que cuando tome la variable por el metodo get o post , y segun la variable se actualice la pagina pero solo una vez.

mi idea es hacer :

ejemplo :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

actualizar=<?php   if(isset($_GET["actualizar"])){  
      echo $_GET["actualizar"];}
      else {
        echo "null";
      }
      ?>;

 if (actualizar!=null ){
  /* aca viene mi duda :
  cambiar la url (ya que viene con la variable
  ejemplo index.php?actualizar="si"),
  limpiar las variables quedando url =  index.php;
  osea la limpio para que no quede en un bucle infinito.

  y despues : pero me sigue dando el bucle infinito.


  location.reload(true);
 }

<script>
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es quitar todos los parámetros, podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
if (actualizar!=null ){
    document.location.href = document.location.pathname;
}
```

La idea es que `document.location.pathname` contiene la parte de la URL sin los parámetros o hash (`#`). Entonces si el parámetro actualizar está especificado, se redireccionará a la página sin parámetros y sin nada. Y así evitas el bucle infinito.

---

Si lo que quieres es quitar sólo el parámetro actualizar, preservando los otros parámetros y el hash, entonces podrías hacer esto:

```
if (actualizar!=null ){
    // obtenemos los parámetros sin el ?
    var paramString = document.location.search.substring(1);
    // lo convertimos en un array partiendo por los &
    var params = paramString.split("&");
    // eliminamos aquellos que comiencen con "actualizar"
    var newParams = params.filter(function(item) { 
        if (item.indexOf("actualizar") != 0) { return item; }
    });
    // los unimos de nuevo
    var newParamsString = newParams.join("&");

    // redireccionamos a la url sin el parámetro actualizar, manteniendo lo demás
    document.location.href = document.location.pathname + 
                             "?" + newParamsString + 
                             document.location.hash;
}
```

Comment: MUchas Gracias Alvaro Montoro , lo voy a implartar y despues te comento.

Comment: todavia no llego a los 15 ptos sino te doy el ok.

Comment: ¿Te sirvió la respuesta? No hay límite de puntos para aceptar las respuestas a tus propias preguntas (lo hay de tiempo).

Comment: Hola alvaro por el momento no tuve tiempo de probarlo , en cuanto lo haga te aviso , pero es genial la explicacion que me brindaste.}

Comment: Buenatas tardes Alvaro , lo estuve probando , y si bien me tira a la pagina principal sin ninguna infomacion como yo queria , lo que falta es que se actualice , hay algun modo de hacer en esa funcion una vez que vaya a la pagina principal se actualice solo una vez con un  location.reload(true);

Comment: @GusCh guarda una variable en el `localStorage` antes de hacer la redirección. Cuando se cargue la página comprueba si la variable existe y bórrala+recarga.

Comment: exacto , muchas Gracias!